# How to include css/js with functions.php in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, include

I'm having trouble including css/js files with functions.php in wordpress and I don't know what im doing wrong looking at other forum posts.

Here is my functions.php

```
<?php

function home_script_enqueue() {

//css

wp_enqueue_style('customstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/home.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');


//js

wp_enqueue_script( 'customjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/home.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts()', 'home_script_enqueue');
```

In my header and footer file I have the wp_head(); and wp_footer(); function inside php tags

When I look at my Wordpress website and I inspect the code not only does nothing change but it doesn't read the the file at all and I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `add_action()` call.

You have:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts()', 'home_script_enqueue');`

It should be:

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'home_script_enqueue');`

Notice the lack of parenthesis in `wp_enqueue_scripts`?

For more details, please check the documentation:

- [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)
- [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)